# What knives can I take with me when going into Georgia?

Tags: air-travel, legal, georgia-country, gear, shopping

What kind of knives can I take with me (by plane) when travelling into Georgia?

Will the small tourist knife be legal? What about survival-like military knives?

I think I would need a knife that could be used for opening cans etc. Is buying something inside Georgia an option, and if so, what price would I be looking at?

Comment: Some types of knives are illegal in some countries. For that, I can't tell you what's allowed in Georgia. As far as traveling by plane goes, as long as you pack it in your checked-in luggage, pretty much every knife will be acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow.. that's a tough one.

The official documents are online at the [Ministry of Justice of Georgia](https://matsne.gov.ge/) but (naturally) they're all in Georgian and even Google Translate couldn't help me find anything there of note. There's an [official English site too](http://www.justice.gov.ge/index.php?lang_id=ENG) but they lack the detailed document search you need to find information this specific.

Meanwhile, the US Department of State has this to say in their [Georgia travel info](http://travel.state.gov/travel/cis_pa_tw/cis/cis_1122.html): `You may not import firearms into Georgia; however, you may bring hunting weapons into the country for a two-week period, based on a valid Georgian hunting license.` They don't mention knives at all but perhaps absence of evidence is evidence of absence in this case.

Then there's the completely unofficial, anecdotal accounts I've turned up elsewhere on the web:

- Centurion, a hostile environment training provider, [claimes that](http://www.centurionsafety.net/Countries/Georgia.html) `It is normal for most men in Georgia to carry firearms`. (To be taken with salt due to their business interests.)
- This article in the [BBC World News](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-13680304) also claims many students now carry knives to school due to an increase in bullying. (Doesn't mention if it's legal.)
- The author of [this travel guide](http://www.hansrossel.com/travel-information/georgia-tbilisi/traveling.htm), suggests Swiss Knives and Leathermans as good gifts for a host family. (Might be stupid.)

These are about as far as you can get from an official source but they do paint the picture of a society either without strong concealed weapon laws or at least very poor enforcement. It may just be that my Google-Fu is weak today but I get the distinct feeling Georgia doesn't have any knife laws to speak of.

(Oh but obviously don't take them in your carry on!)

Comment: which leads to the most logical advice: call your nearest embassy or consulate and ask their legal expert. That's the only way to get an official answer short of putting in a call with a Georgian judge or police chief directly.

Comment: I did attempt to contact the Georgian consult in Australia but the reply wasn't very helpful, it was: `Ill ask .if I get a reply Ill email you.personally I dont advise it`

Answer (score 1):

I've never, in no country I've ever been, had trouble carrying a Swiss Army knife. But then I've never been stopped and searched by any law enforcement officer anywhere, ever, except during routine security checks at airports or large events and I never carry it on my person there (always fly it in checked luggage, leave it at home for things like concerts and other events).